# re.match('any item from a list') with python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to generalize a python script designed to analyze three specific plants to be able to analyze any kind of species. I have a piece of code:

```
dump=open('dump')
for i in dump:
  if re.match('CON|VEN|PLE',i):
     print i
```

and I would like to say:

```
dump=open('dump')
list = ['CON','PLE','VEN']
for i in dump:
  if re.match('any item from my list',i): # How can I ask for item from a list that match?
     print i
```

Because I have to reproduce this code several time with lots of different IDs from different lists.

Answer (score 4):

`i` is a line in your file so for clarity I will call it `line`

```
 if set(line.split()).intersection(list_of_words)
```

if you really want to do it with regex

```
 if re.find("|".join(sorted(list_of_words,key=len,reverse=True)),line)
```

should work ...

Answer (score 2):

You could turn it around - rather than `re.match(any...)` do:

```
if any(re.match(item, i) for item in lst):
```

Note that `list` is a bad variable name, as it shadows the built-in.

Comment: a good answer ... but probably not super efficient (if list was alot bigger than the example provided ...(and tended to find most matches toward the end of the list or something)) but very straight forward

Comment: @JoranBeasley your answer is certainly more efficient!